# Field not found on serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a REST API using DRF, and am currently stuck with modeling the endpoint `/api/v1/venues/1/packages/`. A GET request on this is giving me this error:

> AttributeError at /api/v1/venues/1/packages/
>
> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `item_type` on serializer `MenuItemSerializer`.
>
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `ManyRelatedManager` instance.
>
> Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'item_type'.

Here are the participating models:

```
class MenuItemType(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'menu_item_types'
    
    name = models.TextField()

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'menu_items'
    
    name = models.TextField()
    item_type = models.ForeignKey('MenuItemType', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PackageItems(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'package_items'
    
    package = models.ForeignKey('Package', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey('MenuItem', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    comments = models.TextField(null=True)

class Package(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'packages'
    
    name = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2)
    comments = models.TextField(null=True)

    venue = models.ForeignKey('Venue', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_items = models.ManyToManyField('MenuItem', through='PackageItems')
```

and the serializers:

```
class MenuItemTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuItemType
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class MenuItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_type = MenuItemTypeSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'item_type']

class PackageItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu_items = MenuItemSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = PackageItems
        fields = ['id', 'menu_items', 'quantity', 'comments']

class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu_items = MenuItemSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['id', 'venue_id', 'name', 'price', 'comments', 'menu_items']
```

Let me admit up-front that I'm new Django and DRF and might be making some stupid mistake. Criticism, therefore, is most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to set `many=True` in a `MenuItemSerializer` when you call it from related manager

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu_items = MenuItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['id', 'venue_id', 'name', 'price', 'comments', 'menu_items']
```

Comment: That worked! Please also explain a little. Why does `many=True` matter and why its absence was causing an error. :-)

Comment: @dotslash it calls special `many_init` serializer method to serialize a list of objects instead of single object. So when you need to represent a quryset you should use flag `many=True`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense now.